# Thread sanitizer causes the app to freeze up constantly?

Tags: ios, xcode, thread-sanitizer

Whenever I start the app up with the thread sanitizer on, it just freezes up. When I pause execution, I always see some sort of tsan function call that the main thread has become completely stuck on. How can I prevent this? I'm using Xcode 8.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that "Pause on issues" is uncheck when you start thread sanitizer. It may be paused because it has found any bug while executing.

Comment: The first time I used it, it would pause appropriately and show me all of the interfering threads. Now, it's just a deadlock and the only way I can see the stack trace is to pause it myself.